# How is "every man be fully persuaded in his own mind" not contradictory to the "narrow is the way leading to life"?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, paul-apostle, romans, religious-practice, eternal-life

The following verses seem to imply that Paul was liberal when it came to the believers' practice of their faith in the Lord:

> One man esteemeth one day above another: another esteemeth every day
>   alike. **Let every man be fully persuaded in his own mind**. He that
>   regardeth the day, regardeth it unto the Lord; and he that regardeth
>   not the day, to the Lord he doth not regard it. He that eateth, eateth
>   to the Lord, for he giveth God thanks; and he that eateth not, to the
>   Lord he eateth not, and giveth God thanks. (KJV, Romans 14:5-6)

However, the Lord's words on the way leading to life seem more strict:

> Enter ye in at the strait gate: for wide is the gate, and broad is the
>   way, that leadeth to destruction, and many there be which go in
>   thereat: Because **strait is the gate, and narrow is the way, which**
>   **leadeth unto life**, and few there be that find it. (KJV, Matthew
>   7:13-14)

So, how are Paul's words not contradictory to the Lord's words? I think there must be some explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "liberal"? Why do you think they are contradictory?

Comment: @curiousdannii - "**What do you mean by "liberal"?**" - By liberal I mean suggesting many ways as acceptable. "**Why do you think they are contradictory?**" - The Lord's words seem to imply only one way and quite a narrow one at that. (I personally don't think they are contradictory, however, I don't see yet HOW they are not contradictory).

Comment: This question seems to be an example of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/266429). See the comments on timf's answer for why I conclude that.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude - "**This question seems to be an example of the XY problem**" - The original setting of the XY problem is "you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work", in my case, however, I don't have any ready solution on my mind.

Answer (score 2):

**How is “every man be fully persuaded in his own mind” not contradictory to the “narrow is the way leading to life”?**

The Romans verse in context is referring to disputes between Christians.

The "narrow way" refers to those from the population at large who have become Christian.

Even the nation of Israel had the problem of the "broad way" that leads to destruction.

> Judges 17:6  In those days there was no king in Israel, but every man
>   did that which was right in his own eyes.

The Romans verse is talking about those who have already entered in by the narrow gate by allowing Christians the elbow room to have their doctrine a little wrong.

> Romans 14:2  For one believeth that he may eat all things: another,
>   who is weak, eateth herbs.

Comment: "**The "narrow way" refers to those from the population at large who have become Christian**" - Can you, please, elaborate to prove this point.

Comment: @brilliant It's self-evident from the passage. And anyway, the verses quoted in this answer _already_ demonstrate this. What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude - (1) "**It's self-evident from the passage ... What exactly do you want to see?**" - I want to see how exactly it is self-evident. There is no word "Christian" in the sermon on the mountain. The listeners of the sermon were only the Jewish people (Mat. 6:7). The contents of the sermon are full of allusions to or direct quotations from the Jewish Law, thus, it could only be properly understood by the Jews then. It was spoken long

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude - (2) before Jesus said "I am not sent but unto the lost sheep of the house of Israel" (Mat.15:24) or before He even started disclosing that He would be crucified and resurrected (Mat.16:21). It speaks about the kingdom of God, and it has no mentioning of the Body of Christ. Nor does it contain the word "Church".

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude - (3) Such key concepts of the Christian faith like the Body of Christ, the Church, the Holy Spirit, crucifixion, resurrection or regeneration are not found in the sermon on the mountain. Besides just saying "it's self evident", one should bring more evidence to make a case that the sermon on the mountain was addressed to Christians and not just to the Jews.

Comment: @brilliant I think that's a separate question, and one that probably should have been asked first since it seems to be the _core_ issue. Asking something like "what evidence is there that the Sermon on the Mount is addressed to Christians rather than Jews?" would probably be a good idea. It's a big topic.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude - "**I think that's a separate question ... It's a big topic**" - So, how come then you said "It's self-evident from the passage"?!

Answer (score 2):

What you see is narrowness and broadness, so you see the two passages as contradictory. But if we look at their details, we see that they have nothing to do with each other.

Jesus is talking about destruction, roads, and gates while Paul is talking about days and food. Jesus is using roads and gates figuratively while Paul is talking about days and food literally. They are not talking about the same thing; Paul's words cannot have anything to do with destruction and gates; days and food don't seem to link up with roads and gates.

At first glance, they are contradictory. However, Jesus' words from the Sermon on the Mount and Paul's words are different sides of the same Kingdom of God. Jesus is possibly talking about religion per se, the rituals and traditions of men. The broad way would then be to follow the traditions everyone else is following, while the narrow way is to pursue the life-giving one, living day by day trusting in God. The kingdom is all about the King, and many miss him on the broad way.

Paul affirms the narrow way in regards to food and days. Some Jews still had attachments to Moses' laws about eating meat, while still having saving faith in Jesus. If they shun meat according to the law because it pleases Jesus, then it is okay for that person. If another Jewish person can eat pork and thank Jesus for it, then it is fine for that person. It is acceptable for both because in either case the King is kept in view; their relationship to the King defines what they do.

Jesus warns his hearers to watch which way they are going; Paul affirms his readers to continue in what they do when Jesus is kept in view. Both have the same kingdom in view, but their message is different.

Comment: "**Just take care to study the differences between the passages and not just the broad ideas in each**" - You can rest assured that I did. Perhaps, the question of why certain believers did not want to eat certain types of food could help look into this case deeper and see the possible connection between the Paul's words and the Lord's. It is quite possible that some Christians did not want to eat some meats because they were afraid that eating those meats would lead them to destruction mentioned by the Lord. After all, in Acts 15:29 Apostles themselves forbade them to eat certain meats.

Comment: @brilliant, read this, then you'll know that Jesus isn't taking our food seriously, but is concerned about the hidden affairs of the heart: Mark 7:15-23.

Comment: "**read this, then you'll know...**" - I think this is a good and valid explanation on the  matter of food - mainly, that the words "narrow is the way" are not about food. You may want to include Mark 7:15-23 explanation in your answer. Now there still is a need to explain other practices, that is, non-food related ones - Paul's liberal words are not only about food: "_He that regardeth the day, regardeth it unto the Lord; and he that regardeth not the day, to the Lord he doth not regard it_"

Comment: I went ahead and gave the context of each passage to flesh out my answer.